# Convert array of strings to array of numbers Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a couple of arrays of numbers that are in string format, like:

```
A = ["1046.7779999999038", "1106.244999999035", "833.5839999999735"]
```

I want to use the numbers in number format further for some calculations and need them in numeric format, so that I have an array of numbers.

I wanted to use parseInt, but this is not quite right it seems. Maybe I need to split my array first? Ideally I want a function that has an array as input and converts it to the same array in numeric format.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, `parseFloat()` is the conversion function you want to use.  To convert your array in place without creating a new temporary array, you can either use a `for` loop or the `.forEach()` iterator to cycle through the array and convert the elements in place:

```
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    A[i] = parseFloat(A[i]);
}
```

or

```
A.forEach(function(value, index) {
    A[index] = parseFloat(value);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You use the [`parseFloat` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) for parsing floating point numbers.

You can use the [`map` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to parse all of the strings in the array into an array of numbers:

```
A = $.map(A, function(s){ return parseFloat(s); });
```

Comment: `.each()` seems more appropriate here since you can just assign to the existing array rather than create a whole new array.

Comment: @jfriend00: If you want to do that then a plain loop would be more appropriate. You can't assign the parsed values back to the value that you get in the `each` callback, so you have to access the array by index anyway.

Comment: `.each()` or `for` are both fine and better than `$.map()` IMO.

Comment: @jfriend00: This kind of conversion is exactly what the `map` method is intended for, it's up to you if you don't want to use it.

Comment: @jfriend00: Why do you say that it doesn't do a conversion when it clearly does a conversion? I think that you are utterly confused...

Comment: I just meant that it doesn't convert the array elements in place.  It creates a whole new array which you then assign back to the original.  Never mind.  I've offered my own answer that converts the actual array elements in place without making a new array.

Answer (score 2):

You can call [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) on each member of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use parseFloat:

```
function convert(arr){
    var ret=[];
    for(i in arr){
    ret.push (parseFloat(I));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let a separate array B store all your number conversions.

```
var convert = function() {
    for(var i=0;i<A.length< i++){
        B[i]=Number(A[i]);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$.each(A, function(i, el) {
  A[i] = Number(el)
});
```

```js
var A = ["1046.7779999999038", "1106.244999999035", "833.5839999999735"];

$.each(A, function(i, el) {
  A[i] = Number(el)
});

console.log(typeof (A[0] && A[1] && A[2]) === "number", A)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```